# How to find a list of Dates from a Start-Date and End-Date

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Find missing dates for a given range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3388344/find-missing-dates-for-a-given-range)
>   [Create an array or List of all dates between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3738748/create-an-array-or-list-of-all-dates-between-two-dates)

From two dates of data type `DateTime` representing a `date of start` and a `date of end`.

I need return an array or List which contain all the dates in DateTime format.

Considering the faster code for performance reason. Could anyone please point me out in the right direction with sample source code?

Example

INPUT

```
startDate =  25/01/2013
endDate = 31/01/2013
```

RESULT

```
25/01/2013
26/01/2013
27/01/2013
28/01/2013
29/01/2013
30/01/2013
31/01/2013
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Enumerable.Range`:

```
var startDate = new DateTime(2013, 1, 25);
var endDate = new DateTime(2013, 1, 31);
int days = (endDate - startDate).Days + 1; // incl. endDate 

List<DateTime> range = Enumerable.Range(0, days)
    .Select(i => startDate.AddDays(i))
    .ToList();
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/W4gdLa)

Answer (score 1):

You can create extension method:

```
public static IEnumerable<DateTime> GetDatesTo(this DateTime start, DateTime end)
{
    DateTime date = start;

    while(date <= end)
    {
        yield return date;
        date = date.AddDays(1);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
DateTime startDate = new DateTime(2013, 1, 25);
DateTime endDate = new DateTime(2013, 1, 31);

foreach(var date in startDate.GetDatesTo(endDate))
    Console.WriteLine(date);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Demo
{
    public static class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            foreach (var date in DateRange(new DateTime(2013, 01, 25), new DateTime(2013, 01, 31)))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(date.ToShortDateString());
            }
        }

        public static IEnumerable<DateTime> DateRange(DateTime start, DateTime end)
        {
            for (DateTime date = start; date <= end; date = date.AddDays(1))
            {
                yield return date;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

linq version

```
        DateTime[] dates = { /*...25/01/2013, 26/01/2013*/ };
        DateTime start = DateTime.Parse("25/01/2013");
        DateTime end = DateTime.Parse("31/01/2013");
        var q = (from a in dates
                 where a.Date >= start.Date && a.Date <= end.Date
                 select a).ToList();
```

Comment: from the question seems that the `dates` is the almost result, not an input...

Comment: the main issue here, is the range of date :D